# Distinct (or group by) using filesort and temp table

Tags: mysql, indexing, group-by, distinct

I know there are similar questions on this but I've got a specific query / question around why this query

```
EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT RSubdomain FROM R_Subdomains WHERE EmploymentState IN (0,1) AND RPhone='7853932120'
```

gives me this output explain

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  RSubdomains index   NULL    RSubdomain  767 NULL    3278    Using where
```

with and index on RSubdomains

but if I add in a composite index on EmploymentState/RPhone

I get this output from explain

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  RSubdomains range   EmploymentState EmploymentState 67  NULL        2   Using where; Using temporary
```

if I take away the distinct on RSubdomains it drops the Using temp from the explain output... but what I don't get is why, when I add in the composite key (and keeping the key on RSubdomain) does the distinct end up using a temp table and which index schema is better here?  I see that the amount of rows scanned on the combined key is far less, but the query is of type range and it's also slower.

Answer (score 1):

**Q: why ... does the distinct end up using a temp table?**

MySQL is doing a range scan on the index (i.e. reading index blocks) to locate the rows that satisfy the predicates (WHERE clause). Then MySQL has to lookup the value of the `RSubdomain` column from the underlying table (it's not available in the index.)  To eliminate duplicates, MySQL needs to scan the values of `RSubdomain` that were retrieved.  The "Using temp" indicates the MySQL is materializing a resultset, which is processed in a subsequent step.  (Likely, that's the set of `RSubdomain` values that was retrieved; given the DISTINCT, it's likely that MySQL is actually creating a temporary table with RSubdomain as a primary or unique key, and only inserting non-duplicate values.

In the first case, it looks like the rows are being retreived in order by `RSubdomain` (likely, that's the first column in the cluster key). That means that MySQL needn't compare the values of all the `RSubdomain` values; it only needs to check if the last retrieved value matches the currently retrieved value to determine whether the value can be "skipped."

**Q: which index schema is better here?**

The optimum index for your query is likely a covering index:

```
... ON R_Subdomains (RPhone, EmploymentState, RSubdomain)
```

But with only 3278 rows, you aren't likely to see any performance difference.

**FOLLOWUP**

Unfortunately, MySQL does not provide the type of instrumentation provided in other RDBMS (like the Oracle event 10046 sql trace, which gives actual timings for resources and waits.)

Since MySQL is choosing to use the index when it is available, that is probably the most efficient plan. For the best efficiency, I'd perform an OPTIMIZE TABLE operation (for InnoDB tables and MyISAM tables with dynamic format, if there have been a significant number of DML changes, especially DELETEs and UPDATEs that modify the length of the row...) At the very least, it would ensure that the index statistics are up to date.

You might want to compare the plan of an equivalent statement that does a GROUP BY instead of a DISTINCT, i.e.

```
SELECT r.RSubdomain
  FROM R_Subdomains r
 WHERE r.EmploymentState IN (0,1)
   AND r.RPhone='7853932120'
 GROUP
    BY r.Subdomain
```

For optimum performance, I'd go with a covering index with RPhone as the leading column; that's based on an assumption about the cardinality of the RPhone column (close to unique values), opposed to only a few different values in the EmploymentState column. That covering index will give the best performance... i.e. the quickest elimination of rows that need to be examined.

But again, with only a couple thousand rows, it's going to be hard to see any performance difference. If the query was examining millions of rows, that's when you'd likely see a difference, and the key to good performance will be limiting the number of rows that need to be inspected.

Comment: Thank you for the great explaination.  I did try the covering index you described (actually I had employement state as the first of the three) but it end up giving me the same "using temporary"... but! it also includes "using index" .  This is what I get --> "Using where, using index, Using temporary"  and the rows column is equal to 2

Comment: So, I guess I'm also asking .. in the end is row-examined = 2 and "Using tempory" a better sql query than rows examined = 3000 and "Using Where" .  How do you balance those factors and know your query is as efficient as possible ?

Comment: thank you :)  Last question and I tried to search for this already but does mysql innodb lock rows that it examines or does a row lock occur for other reasons.

Comment: nvm, think I found what I was looking for.. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locks-set.html

Comment: @user2970770: to improve concurrency, for your query, you'd want an index the RPhone column first, then the EmploymentState column ( assuming that there are large number of values for RPhone, and only a few values for EmploymentState... the goal is for the index range scan to examine (and lock) the minimum number of blocks. Having the RSubdomain column also in the index means that MySQL can satisfy the query directly from the index (explain will show "Using index") without having to visit any blocks in the underlying table.